# My first answer is accepted and has two upvotes, yet I have no reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I joined Stack Overflow last week when I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246412/last-insert-id-always-returns-0-rmysql-separate-connection-issue) I wanted to answer. If I understand things correctly, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246412/last-insert-id-always-returns-0-rmysql-separate-connection-issue/26764019#26764019) has been upvoted twice and also accepted. And I did receive the Teacher and Revival badges for it. Yet when I look at [my reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4219781/ilari-scheinin?tab=reputation&sort=time), it shows no changes and is thus still at one.

What is it about the reputation system that I'm not understanding here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That question is community wiki, which automatically makes your own answer community wiki as well. You do not receive any reputation for posts that are community wiki.

There is no good reason why this question is CW, it is due to an old mechanism that was removed a while ago. So this should not really happen for current questions.

Answer (score 2):

The question that you answered is a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) which means that you don't receive any reputation from that answer. From the link I included.

> Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.
>
> Accepting an answer marked as community wiki does not affect its author's reputation.

So while you've posted an answer, you won't gain or lose reputation for it.